# Relative URLs for a particular custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

Is it possible to make URLs relative for just a singular custom post type? I used these 2 lines in make just my custom post types to use relative URLs.

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wp_make_link_relative' );  // Custom post type link
add_filter( 'post_type_archive_link', 'wp_make_link_relative' ); // Post type archive link
```

This worked great, until I realized I had a trickle down problem of my events no longer resolving properly if they were shown on a sub-domain. My site has a few different mapped sub-domains, so I'm now looking to narrow my add_filter to just the custom post type I need instead of all of them.

Comment: look at the first example for [`post_type_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link)

Comment: @Milo Thanks, that seems to have got me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At @milo's suggestion, I used the post_type_link example and adapted it to my needs. This made it so only my chosen post type would be relative, while leaving any other custom post types functioning as usual.

```
function make_yourposttype_relative ( $url, $post ) {
    if ( 'yourposttype' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wp_make_link_relative' );  // Custom post type link
        add_filter( 'post_type_archive_link', 'wp_make_link_relative' ); // Post type archive link
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'make_yourposttype_relative', 10, 2 );
```